# flutter doctor --android-licenses proxy server error

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, frontend

I've recently downloaded android sdk when I ran flutter doctor it complained and said     Android license status unknown. I've ran flutter doctor --android-licenses as it said and I had this error

```
Error: The proxy server URL extracted from HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY environment 
variable could not be parsed. Either specify the correct URL or unset the environment 
variable.
 java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 127.0.0.1:56885
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:645)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:541)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:488)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.<init>(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:470)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:152)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:134)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:58)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:49)
```

Note: I've already installed Android SDK Command-Line Tools

Any recommmendations how to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you checked [this github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24854)? There may be something helpful there.

Answer (score 0):

In your flutter command line run `Get-ChildItem Env:` 
This will list all your local environment variables. 
 
Make sure that 'HTTP_PROXY' and 'HTTPS_PROXY' variables are in that list. 
Then run `Remove-Item -Path Env:http_proxy` and `Remove-Item -Path Env:https_proxy` to delete them

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and just found a solution.

If you encounter this particular error, you probably use a proxy on your PC and have not set the proxy configuration correctly.

The error `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 127.0.0.1:56885` means you did not include a protocol `HTTP` or `HTTPS` in the URL.

The solution is to either specify the correct URL or unset the environment variable as the error suggests.

To fix this, re-run the commands you used to set up the proxy and don't forget to include `http://` or `https://` in the URLs.

**On Windows Command Prompt:**

```
set http_proxy=http://hostname:port
set https_proxy=https://hostname:port
```

**On Linux/macOS:**

```
export http_proxy=http://hostname:port
export https_proxy=https://hostname:port
```

**NB**

1. On [geo_n](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17368653/geo-n)'s case, the command is `set http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:56885` instead of `set http_proxy=127.0.0.1:56885`
2. If you are not using a proxy server or don't wish to use one, you can remove the proxy config with the command `set http_proxy=` and `set https_proxy=` or try using [Shaleniy Legnb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18503606/shaleniy-leginb)'s answer to unset the environment variable